# Where can I learn about how to use html5 for client-side database apps?

Tags: html

I would like to begin using the client-side database functionality of html5, but I don't know where to go for a good introduction/tutorial/how-to.  I've been coding (x)html for years and years, so I'm not so much interested in a "here's the `<head>` element" type of introduction; I want to learn about what's *new* in html5 in general, and client-side db in particular.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you found the reply useful please tick it as answered :)

Answer (score 3):

Alex,
  I wrote up a detailed method of how to do it at: http://wecreategames.com/blog/?p=219 - including source code to download.  Here's a few snippets:

```
function picsInitDatabase() {
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            console.log('Databases are not supported in this browser');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'picsGeoDB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'Pictures Geotagged database';
            var maxSize = 5000000; // in bytes
            picsDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            console.log("Database is setup: "+picsDB);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        // Error handling code goes here.
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error "+e+".");
        }
        return;
    } 
}
```

And here's a function to update the table:

```
function picsUpdateTables(dataID) { 
    picsDB.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            var p = data[dataID];
            transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO geopictures (id, secret, server, farm, title, latitude, longitude, accuracy, datetaken, ownername) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
            [p.id, p.secret, p.server, p.farm, p.title, p.latitude, p.longitude, p.accuracy, p.datetaken, p.ownername] );
            transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO photodata (picid, encodedtext) VALUES (?, ?)", [p.id, serializeCanvasByID(p.id)] );
        }
    );  
}
```

See the blog post for examples of how to do SQL SELECTS, and a video showing how to test it on a few browsers.

Comment: The downloadable source code makes this completely worthwhile. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://www.weboshelp.net/webos-tutorials/156-palm-webos-html5-database-storage-tutorial :)

Another useful link:

- http://www.scribd.com/doc/4012693/Abusing-HTML-5-Structured-Clientside-Storage

Comment: (i know it's aimed at the palm web OS but it's because they use the latest webkit build that supports HTML5 client side db storage)

Comment: Thanks.  Weird thing, though: I checked out the first link above, and it doesn't render correctly, in either Safari 4 or Firefox 3 (both on Mac OS X).  It's as if the text is shifted 20px or so left, and therefore out of the window.  Is it just me?

Third link looks promising; I'll probably check it out more thoroughly tomorrow.  Thanks again.