# Javascript libraries that allow for SQL-like queries on JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, mysql, json

Say our JSON data comes from a single MySQL table:

```
someJSON =    [ { name: 'bill' , sex:'M', income:50000 },
                { name: 'sara' , sex:'F', income:100000 },
                 ...
               ];
```

And say the pseudo-code is:

**"Get all the person objects of all `sex:F` of `income` > 60000`".**

Are there any javascript libraries that would allow one to code such queries on this JSON data using a SQL or SQL-like syntax.

In case you are curious, some context:

I am making the front-end of a data analysis web service for my organization without knowing what the future backend will be. In the future they will migrate their data from MS Access tables to some-sort of MySQL-type database. Until then I am using static JSON files to start development and was thinking it may be helpful for them in the future to have my javascript queries appear as MySQL queries. (The current MS Access database is unreachable from the web.)

Comment: This question should be opened,..

Comment: Check out Apache Drill: https://drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out [jslinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/):

```
var myList = [
            {FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
            {FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
            {FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Sutherland"},
            {FirstName:"John",LastName:"Ronald"},
            {FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pinkerton"}
            ];

var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
                   .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
                   .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
                   .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try [alasql.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). It is pure JavaScript client-side SQL-server, where you can do queries over JSON objects.

```
   // Fill table with data
   var data = [ { name: 'bill' , sex:'M', income:50000 },
                { name: 'sara' , sex:'F', income:100000 }];

   // Do the query
   console.log(alasql("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE sex='F' AND income > 60000",[data]));
```

Try this in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/38hj2uwy/40/)

Answer (score 9):

I use Taffydb. 
TaffyDB is an opensouce library that brings database features into your JavaScript applications.
http://taffydb.com/

Comment: We recently started using TaffyDB in our web app development and it has greatly simplified a lot of the things we are doing. There are a couple points that it's weird about, but overall it's pretty magical. :)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a few linq like javascript libraries in past google searches.

Edit- here's a couple
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/
http://jslinq.codeplex.com/
http://jsinq.codeplex.com/ <-- [really cool playground for this one](http://kaijaeger.com/downloads/jsinq/playground/)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in checking out MongoDB, a JSON-style data store with full queryability.  Here is its [query syntax:](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying)

```
db.users.find({'last_name': 'Smith'})
```

For your example question:

```
db.users.find({'sex': 'F', 'income' : {$gt : 60000}})
```

Comment: good suggestion in general, but poor answer to this question IMHO

Answer (score 1):

There is also [JsonSql](http://www.trentrichardson.com/jsonsql/) which seems to be similar like what you are looking for. Only problem is that it hasn't been updated in 12/30/2007.  Still the code is there to grab and play with.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers/versions you must support, I would strive to use [HTML5 client-side SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990869/where-can-i-learn-about-how-to-use-html5-for-client-side-database-apps), pushing my JSON data into one or more tables and harnessing the power of true SQL queries.

Here's the draft spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Comment: Thanks...because of your answer I have started to research IndexDB , a client-side database for Firefox 4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IndexedDB_primer

Answer (score 1):

There is also a XPath style query called JSONPath that I like http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

And there is this http://code.google.com/p/jfunk/
Which users jQuery style selectors to filter data

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but I just came here through a Google search. I'm just following a talk about [objeq](https://github.com/agilosoftware/objeq). Looks pretty promising and very much what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="linq.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var jsonArray = [
    { "user": { "id": 100, "screen_name": "d_linq" }, "text": "to objects" },
    { "user": { "id": 130, "screen_name": "c_bill" }, "text": "g" },
    { "user": { "id": 155, "screen_name": "b_mskk" }, "text": "kabushiki kaisha" },
    { "user": { "id": 301, "screen_name": "a_xbox" }, "text": "halo reach" }
]
// ["b_mskk:kabushiki kaisha", "c_bill:g", "d_linq:to objects"]
var queryResult = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .Where(function (x) { return x.user.id < 200 })
    .OrderBy(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name })
    .Select(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text })
    .ToArray();
// shortcut! string lambda selector
var queryResult2 = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .Where("$.user.id < 200")
    .OrderBy("$.user.screen_name")
    .Select("$.user.screen_name + ':' + $.text")
    .ToArray();

console.log(queryResult);
console.log(queryResult2);
 </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: from where you obtained `linq.js`?