# New javascript/jquery library that allows for SQL-like queries on JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

This question was asked about a year ago to [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720494/javascript-libraries-that-allow-for-sql-like-queries-on-json-data). As I've done google searches for answers to this question, all the libraries I've found seem to not have had any activity for about a year. I'm just wondering if anyone out there is aware of any libraries that are currently maintained, or what other alternatives people do?

I'm looking to do some client-side data filtering, and I'm open to other suggestions beyond writing my own functions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [taffydb](http://taffydb.com/) and [web sql database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript library. It supports queries on JSON arrays with full SQL functionality.

Here is and example:

```
 <script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     var cars = [{model:'Mazda', price:20000}, {model:'Toyota', price:25000}, 
        {model:'Ford', price:22000}];

     var res = alasql("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE price > 21000",[cars]);

     console.log(res);
 </script>
```

Try this example [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/0f1t3q0g/).