# How to apply complex data filters like SQL where clause on JSON

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am Using Json to represent data at client side(javascript), I converted .net datatable object to json and now need to apply filter on Json data.  I used _.where to apply basic data filter , but need complex filtering like:

```
where = (stundentID = 55 and school='abc') AND (City='xyz' or City ='abc')
```

Its a basic type of filtration that we used in Oracle or sql server queries.  Now how can i apply such mechanism using underscore.js or some thing equivelant on Json or javascript structures. I might also need to do query of getting Top N record , using aggregation [ Sum(sales)==500] at javascript.  Waiting for your valuable suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Check for reference the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720494/javascript-libraries-that-allow-for-sql-like-queries-on-json-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have this JSON represented as a regular JavaScript object—there's no such thing as a JSON object, after all—you're best bet would likely be to use [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

You'd be able to do things like:

```
var studentFilteredArray = 
          Enumerable.From(students)
                    .Where(function(s) { return s.studenId == 55;  })
                    .OrderBy(function(s) { return s.LastName; })
                    .ToArray();
```

Or from your example above:

```
.Where(function(s) { 
      return s.studentID === 55 && s.school === 'abc' && (s.City === 'xyz' || s.City === 'abc') 
});
```

Comment: Is this a linq question or a javascript question?

Comment: @Saju - it's a JavaScript question.  I'm recommending he use the linq.js utility to accomplish what he wants.

Comment: Thanks, for a nice solution, though i am bit concern about its performance.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Any idea how efficient linq.js is? Compared to something like underscore.js

Comment: @Adam Rackis: No worries. Cheers for introducing me to it mate.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try [alasql.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql), where you can use standard SQL SELECT WHERE statement. Alasql was specially designed to work with JSON arrays like tables in database.

```
// Create database and describe the table
var db = new alasql.Database();
db.exec('CREATE TABLE students ([studentID] INT, school STRING, [City] STRING)');

// Assign you array here
db.tables.students.data = [
       {studentID: 55, school: 'abc', City:'abc'},
       {studentID: 56, school: 'klm', City:'xyz'},
       {studentID: 57, school: 'nyz', City:'xyz'}
    ];

// Use regular SQL 
console.log(db.exec("SELECT * FROM students "
  +" WHERE ([studentID] = 55 AND school='abc') AND ([City]='xyz' OR [City] ='abc')"));
```

Try this example [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/606ksx2g/1/).

Comment: it looks a promising option too and I'll surely like to give it a try.