# Merge source JSON string to target with similar keys but different structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have two JSON strings as shown below:

```
source = [
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "values": ["User Support"],
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": ["M"],
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": ["CA"],
    "enabled": false
  }
]
```

---

```
target = [{
    "name": "test1",
    "values": [{
        "value": "User Support",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "Engineering",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "Implementation",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": [{
        "value": "M",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "F",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "notEnabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": [{
        "value": "CA",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "EN",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  }
]
```

I want to merge both these JSON strings into target and the resultant should look like:

```
target = [{
    "name": "test1",
    "values": [{
        "value": "User Support",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "value": "Engineering",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "Implementation",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": [{
        "value": "M",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "value": "F",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": [{
        "value": "CA",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "value": "EN",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  }
]
```

So, what I am trying to do is search in target string for name as test1, test2.... and then set the selected field as true if the value is found in source JSON string. Same is the case for enabled field.

First thing that comes to my mind is to use nested for each loops and check for the keys.
Is there any other better way to do this in Javascript?

Note that there could be other keys present inside target string, but we don't bother about them unless they are present in source string.

Comment: I dont know if this is what you mean with "a better eay", but maybe this is something for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720494/javascript-libraries-that-allow-for-sql-like-queries-on-json-data

Comment: Have you tried anything? This doesn't look too complicated. Just iterate over your source and find the appropriate places in target.

Comment: No, given your structure of `values`, you'll need to use looping instead of being able to lookup. Nested loops are totally fine, only if your source has very large arrays of `values` (not just single values in them) it would make sense to build a `Map` for each target. Also, if the two arrays are always sorted in the same order, you can take advantage of that.

Comment: yes i have tried nested loops and it looks something like this:


`for(let i = 0; i < source.length; ++i)
      for(let j = 0; j < target.length; ++j){
        if(_.isEqual(source[i]["name"], target[j]["name"])){
          target[j]["enabled"] = source[i]["enabled"];
          for(let k = 0; k < target[j]["values"].length; ++k)
            for(let l = 0; l < source[i]["values"].length; ++l)
              if(_.isEqual(target[j]["values"][k]["value"],source[i]["values"][l]))
                target[j]["values"][k]["selected"] = true;
        }
      }`

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't mind lodash:**

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const sourceJSON = '[{"name":"test1","values":["User Support"],"enabled":false},{"name":"test2","values":["M"],"enabled":true},{"name":"test3","values":["CA"],"enabled":false}]';
const targetJSON = '[{"name":"test1","values":[{"value":"User Support","selected":false}, {"value":"Engineering","selected":false},{"value":"Implementation","selected":false}],"enabled":false},{"name":"test2","values":[{"value":"M","selected":false},  {"value":"F","selected":false} ],"notEnabled":false},{ "name":"test3","values": [{"value":"CA","selected":false},{"value":"EN","selected":false}],"enabled":false}]';

const source = JSON.parse(sourceJSON);
const target = JSON.parse(targetJSON);

const sourceNormalized = source.map((obj) => (
  { ...obj, values: [{value: obj.values[0], selected: true}] }
));

const merged = _.defaultsDeep(sourceNormalized, target);
console.dir(merged, {depth: null});
// [ { name: 'test1',
//     values: [
//       { value: 'User Support', selected: true },
//       { value: 'Engineering', selected: false },
//       { value: 'Implementation', selected: false }
//     ],
//     enabled: false
//   },
//   { name: 'test2',
//     values: [ 
//       { value: 'M', selected: true }, 
//       { value: 'F', selected: false } 
//     ],
//     enabled: true,
//     notEnabled: false
//   },
//   { name: 'test3',
//     values: [
//       { value: 'CA', selected: true },
//       { value: 'EN', selected: false }
//     ],
//     enabled: false} ] 

result = JSON.stringify(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69749888/13658816) using lodash is a very good approach. In case you are in a situation such as myself (stuck working on a code-base where packages, including lodash, are difficult to get approved-for-use), here is an approach using Vanilla-javascript (+ JSON.stringify):

```js
const delta = [{
    "name": "test1",
    "values": ["User Support"],
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": ["M"],
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": ["CA"],
    "enabled": false
  }
];

const orig = [{
    "name": "test1",
    "values": [{
        "value": "User Support",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "Engineering",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "Implementation",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": [{
        "value": "M",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "F",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "notEnabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": [{
        "value": "CA",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "value": "EN",
        "selected": false
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  }
];

const getTargetJSON = (delta, orig, debug = true) => { // method signature
  const deltaMapper = delta.reduce((f, i) => ({
    ...f,
    [i.name]: {
      values: [...i.values],
      enabled: i.enabled
    }
  }), {});
  const target = orig.map(itm => ({
    ...itm,
    values: itm.values.map(it2 => ({
      ...it2,
      selected: deltaMapper[itm.name].values.includes(it2.value) || false
    })),
    enabled: deltaMapper[itm.name].enabled || false
  }));

  debug && console.log('Merged Target:\n', target);
  return JSON.stringify(target);
};

getTargetJSON(delta, orig); // method call
```

**Approach / Explanation**:

We breakdown the problem into smaller ones.

- First, generate a map using the source (named 'delta' in
  code-snippet)
- Next, iterate through the target (named 'orig') and    utilize the
  map (created above) to determine whether value is    'selected' and
  item is 'enabled'.